# Android not able to scroll up

Tags: android

I have a login layout with two `EditText` and a `Button`. When I'm typing some text in `EditText`, as the keyboard open it overlap the some of my `layout`. I try to scroll up but not able to scroll up layout to be visible. Ｉ'm using Relative Layout to create it. How to solve it? 
Thank you.

Comment: What are you asking ? Share snapshot what you are getting ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place your `EditText`s and `Button` inside a `ScrollView`. Whatever is inside `ScrollView` can be scrolled. So your problem will be solved.

Note that `ScrollView` can host only one child. So you have to place all your `View`s inside a `ViewGroup` like `LinearLayout` or `RelativeLayout`

Although Julia Zhao's answer is correct, it uses `RelativeLayout`. If you use `RelativeLayout` you have to do more work to make your `View`s appear one below the other. So I suggest you to use `LinearLayout` with `android:orientation="vertical"` inside it. It will automatically place one `View` below the other without any extra effort. So you won't issues like one `View` overlapping on other.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="UserName"/>

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:hint="Password"/>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:text="Login"/>
    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Thanks for explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Try nesting everything in a ScrollView, hope this helps.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView 
    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@id/RLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#000000"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        >

              // Your code

    </RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>
```